# Azure API Management/Portal: activate Mocking for "Try Out" in API Portal

Tags: azure, api, policy, portal

I was wondering if there is the possibility to activate mocking for calls to an Azure API Management based API from the API Portal.

I don't want developers who browse the interface catalog and use the "try it" functionality to actually CRUD records from/in the backends. They should only receive a set of predefined data so they can develop against it without messing up the data in the backends.

**Example**

API is created on Azure API Management and productive.
This API is listed in the corresponding Azure API Portal -
a developer now finds that API and wants to try it out:
[image]

**POST /SalesQuote** would create a Sales Quotation in SAP. A developer uses the "try it" button in the developer portal to see the behaviour. The "send" button now actually creates a record in the backend.

Can this be prevented? If so - how? Would this be something that could be achieved within the API policy (i.e. mock data for origin = api portal url)?

The only other option I can think of would be disabling the try it feature - rather a bad solution.

EDIT: general "mocking-enabled" is of course for a productive API no option.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Nacho I researched the policy features more deeply and played around a bit. I came up with the following:

```
<inbound>
  <base />
  <choose>
    <when condition="@(context.User.Groups.Any(Group => Group.Name == "developer-internal"))">
      <mock-response status-code="201" content-type="application/json" />
    </when>
  </choose>
</inbound>
```

This should enable mocking only if the calling user is member of the group "developer-internal" (which are all developer portal users via AAD mapping).

As an alternative I am validating the re-routing option to our test backend instead of mocking the response which would look like this:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.User.Groups.Any(Group => Group.Name == "developer-internal"))">
            <!--mock-response status-code="201" content-type="application/json" /-->
            <set-backend-service base-url="https://esb-test.example.com/restv2/CostObject" />
        </when>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you have to add a policy in the outbound of the API, normally I use it to expose apis that are in development process.

Go to the "Enable response mocking" part of this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/mock-api-responses

Comment: I know about this feature - as mentioned in my post it is no option to enable general mocking for a productive API (as no calls at all would go through). Only calls coming from the "try it" feature in the API portal need to be handled by a mocking service.

Comment: Oh! I Imisread the question then. I've searched a bit and there doesn't seem to be anything like that. We usually have two published environments, one for testing and one for production. Maybe this is a work around for you too!

Comment: We have that too, but the productive environment mirrors "the perfect state" of the API. During development developers will of cource call the dev/test API Management endpoints. But I guess I found a solution, I will answer in a minute :)